# Программное задание поиска для гугл

Tags: google-search

Нужно добавить программно строку поиска для гугла, где иммитировалось печатание текста юзера и результат поиска в реальном гугле. Видел раньше в ответах на этом форуме, как люди давали ссылки, которые переводили на гугл с уже написанным запросом. Бот пишет запрос, затем формирование ответа идет от гугла. Помогите аналогию такую сделать тоже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это в принципе вообще не сложно, просто на сайте с JS лови GET параметр, вроде seacrh, методом `documetnt.location.seacrh` в JS, потом вводи его в копию поискового поля гугла(глянь в коде элемента), печатать текст тебе поможет классная JS библиотека, Typed.Js вот тутор за 2 минуты, который поможет тебе - [Typed js - эффект печатания текста на сайте](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DpXOp1KVnI), а потом просто делаешь запрос на гугл, с изначально полученным текстом. 
Пример: пользователь кликнул по ссылке твойсайт.ex?pos=Найди%мне, на сайте ты ловишь "найди%мне", декодируешь через `str.decodeURI`, эмитируешь печать через Typed.Js, в конце делаешь редирект на гугл, с изначальной строкой `https://www.google.com/search?q=Найди%мне`, вот так `document.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=Найди%мне';`.

Comment: Да, наверное, это то, что надо. Библиотеки Typed.js печатают текст на главной странице google.com? Js код внедряется что ли в чужой сайт или как? Эффект же печати идет на сайте поисковика? Нет?

Comment: Нет, вот зайдите на pugugli.com это просто их сайт, не большая копия гугла, и все.

Comment: да, спасибо, это, то, что мне нужно как раз).